# Ajax auto search in codeigniter

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

AJAX Autosearch

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.8.0.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
        function ajaxSearch() {
            alert('hai');
            var input_data = $('#search_data').val();
            alert(input_data);

            $.ajax({
                  type: "POST",
                  url: "search/auto_search",
                  data: {search_data:input_data},
                  success: function(data1) {
                    alert(data1);
                    // return success
                    if (data1.length > 0) {
                       $('#suggestions').show();
                       $('#autoSuggestionsList').addClass('auto_list');
                       $('#autoSuggestionsList').html(data1);
                    }
                  }
              });
        }
</script>
```

CONTROLLER

```
public function auto_search() {
        $search_data = $this->input->post('search_data');
        //print_r($search_data);  die();
        $query = $this->search_model->autocomplete($search_data);
        // print_r($query);  die();

        foreach ($query->result() as $row):
            echo $row->uid  ;
            echo  $row->name ;
        endforeach;
    }
```

MODEL

```
public function autocomplete($search_data) {

$this->db->select('name');
        $this->db->select('uid');
        $this->db->like('name', $search_data);
        $dt = $this->db->get('tbl_reg', 10);
        //print_r($dt); die();
        return $dt->result();
}
```

When I echo out the search_data in controller I  got the whole  HTML page  whats the reason for that  and would  you please provide  solution for this problem?

Comment: What's the contents of this html page? And what do you **expect** to receive?

Comment: the content of html page is the   view in codeigniter

Comment: @u_mulder   content is  view in codeigniter that  is  whole  html page   and    when i echo out  the search_data        print_r($search_data); die();  in   controller   i  got the  whole  html  page in view...

Answer (score 0):

change in ajax call as well.

```
      <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.8.0.min.js"></script>
       <script type="text/javascript">
      function ajaxSearch() {
        alert('hai');
        var input_data = $('#search_data').val();
        alert(input_data);

        $.ajax({
              type: "POST",
              url: "/search/auto_search",
              data: {search_data:input_data},
              success: function(data1) {
                alert(data1);
                // return success
                if (data1.length > 0) {
                   $('#suggestions').show();
                   $('#autoSuggestionsList').addClass('auto_list');
                   $('#autoSuggestionsList').html(data1);
                }
              }
          });
    }
```

change controller as following.

```
     public function auto_search() {
    $search_data = $this->input->post('search_data');
    //print_r($search_data);  die();
    $query = $this->search_model->autocomplete($search_data);
    // print_r($query);  die();
    $str='';
    foreach ($query as $row):
        $str.=$row->uid  ;
        $str.=$row->name ;
    endforeach;
   echo $str;
}
```

this will work as you are already return result in model and you do not need to use $query->result();

Comment: when i echo out  str  that  is  print_r($str); die();  i got the same  result , hole html page in view.  please provide  another solution.